# Source Insight 4.0 can't parse '#' comments in x86assembly

Tags: assembly, syntax-highlighting, source-insight

I recently use Source Insight 4.0 to inspect the source code of Linux kernel, but find that SI cannot parses the comment starting with '#' correctly in x86 assembly file.

[image: SI cannot parse the assembly code correctly]

As SI doesn't parse the '#' comment, the quotation mark in line 18 make everything after it a multi-line string.

I've viewed SI's document but got little help. Actually I have no idea how to troubleshoot in this case.

I've tried to add a new "Custom Parsing Expression" to x86 Asm Language Properties but failed. The expressions I tried includes:

```
#.*
#.*$
#(.)*$
```

They should match all charactors after '#' in a single line. But they all got the same error like: "Regular expression must contain one group." and I don't know which kinds of 'group' does it need.

[image: Tried to add new custiom parsing expression]

Thanks for guiding!

Comment: I notice that none of your regexes contain exactly one capture group.  `#(.*)$` has one capture group that matches an arbitrary number of characters.  vs. `(.)*` applies the `*` repeat operator to the whole capture group, not the `.` (match any one character) inside it.  I've never used Source Insight so IDK if that's helpful, but it's what I'd try given that error message.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your advice. Both of the two expressions got the same error in the screenshot. It makes me confused about the definition of the ‘group'.

Comment: @PeterCordes Alright, I found that `#\(.*\)` works. It's counterintuitive that `\(` do have a practical usage in regex. But I still cannot make use of it since the options it presents here is to parse more meaningful things like 'function', 'macro' or 'variable'.

Comment: Oh, so it probably uses "basic" regexes like `grep` or `sed` rather than Extended regexes like `egrep` or `sed -E` I guess, where `(` is literal, `\(` starts a capture group (same for `\?` `\|` and some others).  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#REGULAR_EXPRESSIONS .  Not that that helps with your editor, but hopefully helps you understand regexes.